# wp_mail sending mails contenuously

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this problem with this code,it is keep sending mails contenuously to the receiver.

I have the full plugin uploaded to :  " github.com/adu4/immab_invoice " inside it you will find a .json file which is Advanced custom post exported file.

```
                 add_action('save_post','save_post_callback'); 
                function save_post_callback($post_id){
                        global $post;
                        if ($post->post_type == 'immab_invoice')


                            $permalink = get_the_permalink();
                            $post_password = $post->post_password;


                            $to = get_field('kund_epost');




                            $subject = "Logging detaeljar";


                            $message = "Test"; 





                            // More headers
                            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                            $headers .= 'From: <info@example.s>' . "\r\n";



                        wp_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

                    }
```

Comment: Where do you call that function?

Comment: I do call it when i do save my custom post.